# Create an instance of a class referenced by a variable generated in a method

Tags: java, class

Ok so here is what I need to do:

I am reading in a CSV file and need to generate a new instance of a class for each line.

I then need to store the reference variable for the class in a List.

I am ok with most of this but how do I generate a class using a variable

something like this

```
string newClassName;
int a = 1; //counts number of loops

while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine());
{
    newClassName = SS + a;

    LightningStorms newClassName = new LightningStorms();

    a = a + 1;

}
```

I have left out a lot of extra code but its the setting up of the new class that I am interested in.

I am current learning and this is part of an assignment so want to figure most out for myself (there is a lot more to the question than this) but am stuck so any guidance would be very welcome.

Many thanks

Comment: `newClassName` is a `string`.  You cannot use as later as 'LightningStorms`.  Anyway - your question is not clear to me.

Comment: what is the type and value of 'SS' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an instance of a Class object for a particular name using [Class.forName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) - this needs to be a fully qualified class, so `java.lang.String` not `String`.

With the class object, you can construct a new instance using reflection, see [Class.getConstructor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

Comment: Or `Class.newInstance()` if the class has an zero-arg constructor

Comment: so would I put the new name in the brackets as in Class.newInstance(newClassName) or Class.forName(newClassName)?

Comment: Class.forName(newClassName).newInstance()

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SortedMap<String, LightningStorms> myMap = new TreeMap<String, LightningStorms>();
while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine());
{
    String newClassName = SS + a; // or whatever you want
    myMap.put(newClassName, new LightningStorms());
}
```

At the end of the loop you have a map of LightningStorms objects for every line in your CSV file and every object is referenced by your "generated variable". You can access your object by using: myMap.get("referenceVariable") Additionally you can convert to a list and keep the order of the keys:

```
List<LightningStorms> myList = new ArrayList<LightningStorms>(myMap.values());
```

or you can have a List of reference names as well:

```
List<String> myReferences = new ArrayList<String>(myMap.keySet());
```